# How to properly verify data with rsa?

Tags: c#, encoding, rsa, digital-signature

I want to sign a message with a private key and verify it with a public key, but I can't get it to work..

Here is how I sign the data (edited, but still not working):

```
public static string SignData(string message, string privateKey) {

        byte[] plainText = ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);

        var rsaWrite = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsaWrite.FromXmlString(privateKey);

        byte[] signature = rsaWrite.SignData(plainText, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());

        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    }
```

Here is how I test the data (edited, still not working):

```
public static bool VerifyData(string sign, string publicKey, string orig) {

        byte[] signature = Convert.FromBase64String(sign);
        byte[] original = ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(orig);

        var rsaRead = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsaRead.FromXmlString(publicKey);

        if (rsaRead.VerifyData(original, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), signature)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I store the keypair as an xml string inside my account class. This function is executed in the constructor of account.cs:

```
public void addKeys() {

    RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

    privateKey = provider.ToXmlString(true);
    publicKey = provider.ToXmlString(false);
}
```

I test the overall thing with this:

```
string signedHash = Utility.SignData("test" ,account.privateKey);

if (Utility.VerifyData(signedHash, account.publicKey, "test")) {          
    Console.WriteLine("WORKING!");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("SIGNING NOT WORKING");
}
```

Why isn't the overall thing working? My guess is that it doesn't work because of some encoding stuff.

Comment: `return ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(signature);` is wrong and insensible. Just return the byte array `signature`, don't try to make it into a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(signature);
```

The signature is arbitrary binary data, it isn't necessarily legal Unicode/UCS-2. You need to use an arbitrary encoding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding#Encoding_standards) to encode all of the arbitrary data.  The most popular transport for signatures is Base64, so you'd want

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
```

And, of course, use `Convert.FromBase64String` in the verify method.

---

If you're compiling with a target of .NET 4.6 or higher you can also make use of the newer sign/verify API:

```
rsaRead.VerifyData(original, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), signature)
```

would be

```
rsaRead.VerifyData(original, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1)
```

While it might not look simpler, it prevents the allocation and finalization of the SHA1CryptoServiceProvider that the other method did, and it sets up for The Future when you may want to switch from Pkcs1 signature padding to PSS signature padding.  (But the real advantage is that method is on the `RSA` base class instead of the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` specific type).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the code as you said: return has tobase64string, verifydata() now converts the hashed string back into byte[] with frombase64string. The problem is that the code is still not showing the correct result (i edited the code in the first post).

Comment: I copied and pasted the Sign/Verify code as-is (with Base64) and my testing says that it works now. So you must be ending up with a different key, or corrupting data or the signature; but the utility functions are now functionally correct.

Comment: yes, it is working now. I accidently swapped the original and the hashed message in the verify function. Thank you for your help

Comment: @bartonjs, I am trying to use the `.VerifyData` method on my JWT. I split the JWT into the body and the signature. I would expect that the signature should be verified against the body but it fails. Could you please explain what content the 'original' and the 'signature' variable have in your example?

Comment: @Alex_P `original` is the data to be verified, `signature` is the signature. So for JWS `original` would be the UTF-8 encoding of the contents up to, but not including, the second period (`.`); and `signature` would be the base64url-decoded value of the final segment.